# Creating NDWI Matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Firstly, if you don't know, i should tell what is ndwi. Ndwi stands for normalized difference water index. It is a graphical indicator for water and the value range is [-1 1]. Ndwi is defined as follows:

```
(Green - NIR) / (Green + NIR)
```

I am middle of a simple coastline extraction tool based on opencv. I have accomplished it in MATLAB and the result is shown like this:

[image: MATLAB NDWI]

However, opencv version of the result is look like binarized:

[image: OPENCV NDWI]

When i debugged the program, i see that minimum value in the ndwi matrix is zero and this is wrong because it should be -0.8057. The code which is responsible for ndwi calculation (opencv version) as follows:

```
Mat ndwi = (greenRoi - nirRoi) / (greenRoi + nirRoi);
double min;
double max;
minMaxIdx(ndwi, &min, &max);
Mat adjNDWI;
convertScaleAbs(ndwi, adjNDWI, 255 / max);
```

What is the problem in here and how can i achieve to calculate the right ndwi values?

Note:

greenRoi and nirRoi are created in this way:

```
Rect rectangle = boundingRect(Mat(testCorners)); //vector<Point2f> testCorners(4);

Mat testImgGreen = imread((LPCSTR)testImgGreenPath, 0);
Mat testImgNir = imread((LPCSTR)testImgNirPath, 0);

Mat greenRoi(testImgGreen, rectangle);
Mat nirRoi(testImgNir, rectangle);
```

Comment: Could you show some more code, specifically, the creation of greenRoi & nirRoi Mats. What type do they have? What is the range of values in greenRoi & nirRoi?

Comment: the range is from 0 to 255. both are greyscale images and nothing special about being a roi in this application but i'll add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of greenRoi, nirRoi and ndwi  will all be uchar's (Mat will be CV_8UC1).

Let's say greenRoi = 10, nirRoi = 40.

Your answer is not (10 - 40)/(10+40) = -0.6. The answer has to be positive (because it unsigned) and can't be a fraction. According to my calculator, this will give 0.

@Martin Beckett is correct, convert testImgGreen and testImgNir to matrices with a float type and it will work. You need:

```
testImgGreen.convertTo(testImgGreen, CV_32F);
testImgNir.convertTo(testImgNir , CV_32F);

Mat greenRoi(testImgGreen, rectangle);
Mat nirRoi(testImgNir, rectangle);
Mat ndwi = (greenRoi - nirRoi) / (greenRoi + nirRoi);
```

Comment: Thank you for more clear answer. Now, i can get right min values but how can i adjust the color range? It looks brighter than matlab result. http://i.imgur.com/R6tBE1R.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly create a floating point cv::Mat

`cv::Mat image(cols,rows,CV_32FC1)` or `CV_64FC1` if you need doubles